# Android Studio 4.0.1 error "unable to locate adb" while starting emulator on POP OS 20.04

Tags: android-sdk-tools, ubuntu-20.04, android-studio-4.0

I'm facing annoying pop up **Unable to locate adb** while starting emulator.

*But the error is not stopping Emulator from poping up*

[image: Unable to locate adb]

I have tried to uninstalling and installing platform-tools from SDK manager
but no luck!

*I'm running android-studio on POP! OS 20.04. which is based on Ubuntu 20.04*

any kind of help will much appreciated.